# Unable to connect to clusters via console or kubectl, unable to retrieve data (namespaces, pods)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently facing several issues with my clusters. Firstly, I am unable to establish connections to the clusters using both the Google Cloud console and kubectl. Secondly, I cannot retrieve data such as namespaces or pods using these methods. Moreover, I have noticed that I am unable to view or update the services associated with my clusters. It's worth mentioning that the websites hosted on the clusters are still up and running without any apparent issues. However, I am unable to access, update, or perform any actions related to these services.

I have already checked the GCP status and identified a problem with the logging API. Although I initially suspected a quota limit on the logging API, I have confirmed that this is not the cause of the problem. As a result, I'm unable to view logs, establish connections, update services, or determine the underlying cause of these issues. Any guidance or assistance in resolving or identifying the root cause would be greatly appreciated.